# how to find the number of List Items or rows present in the ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I want to find out how many List Items or rows  are present in the ListView. how is it possible?

Comment: `ListView myList = getListView();
int count = myList.getCount();
`

Comment: @VikalpPatel `getListView()` will work if activity is extending ListActivity.

Comment: @SachinG : yeah exactly. For any other activity else than `ListActivity`. You can get ListView through `findViewByID()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the api listView.getCount()

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ListView myList = getListView();
int count = myList.getCount();
```

Here **getCount()** returns size of list

Developers site [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getCount%28%29)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one : -

find your listview by "findviewbyid"  before that you can set the id to find it uniquely.
Then store it in a listview identifier.

e.g : - ListView listview1 = (ListView) findviewbyid(102);
Note : - 102 is set at the time of creation.

After that add items dynamically or statically in listview

Then user the following statement : -

myCount =  listview1.Items.Count;

print the myCount variable you will get the desired output.

Thanks !